# Set up Netbeans with web server for WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Can anyone tell me how i find the core files of WordPress? Because I installed WordPress on the server but I can't find the core files of WordPress in Netbeans. How I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have properly set up your remote project in Netbeans right click on the project in Netbeans and select "Download". A dialog box opens and you can select all remote files to download. Afterwards those will be visible in the Netbeans IDE.

Comment: Can you tell me the project set up steps?

Comment: Look into the Netbeans docs ;-) Remote project is a good start.